# Windows 7 clients cannot access shares on server 2003

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-shares, windows-server-2003

We just installed a suite of Windows 7 Pro 64 bit machines with a Server 2003 Domain Controller.

For some reason the W7 machine cannot connect to the User shares on our DC.

e.g.

admin account: root

If I log onto the server or a Windows XP client with the admin account I can type \server\usershares$ and it will open up the content

If I login in with the same account on a windows 7 client and type that in \server\usershares$ it gives me an error message that the drive may not exist and to contact the network administrator.

Comment: Can you ping the server from a w7 machine (is it all machines or just one?)

Comment: I can ping the server, the firewall is disabled. The even wierder thing is that I exactly the same machines with the same build image but only some of them will not see the drive. The exact message is "You do not have permission to access \\server\usershare$ please contact the system administrator". if i just access the \\Server it will show all open shares and allow me to access them. Surely it cannot be permissions because i am using exactly the same account only the hardware is different.

Comment: Sorry to ask: Are you on the same domain, using the same DNS and on the same subnet? Can you also disable any internet security/anti virus as well.

Comment: Exactly the same domain subnet gateways and dns. Both machines can get the list of shared folders on the server if you run \\servername in the Run command, However one PC can access SpecificShare$ but the other one cant while using the same user account.

Comment: And is this regardless of which user logs onto this PC?

Comment: yes no matter whether you are an administrator or a standard domain user one machine will allow it and the other will not

Comment: Well, this is good - at least we know it's a config issue on the machine. Now it's a process of elimination: Can you see if there is anything in the hosts file: C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc (open with notepad)

Comment: sorry for the delay. I was not able to access the machines yesterday. both hostfiles are identical

Comment: OK - I wonder if the machine name has been entered into a group within group policy on the server. Can you check?

Comment: thank you for the help and advice. I ended up re-imaging the machines and that did the trick. must be some kind of weird corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced recently this problem and the issue was with the time on the server. The server has a problem with the intrnal battery, so, when you shut it down and then up again, it starts with the production date and time (sometime in 2007).

That's ok to the Windows XP clients but not with the Windows 7 ones. Setting the date and time of both server and client right solved the problem for me.